# Residue of $f(z)=\frac{1}{\sin(z)-1}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

I'm trying to find  $$\text{Res}_{z=\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{\sin(z)-1}$$

Since I don't know where to begin writing out the Laurent series expansion for $f$ I assume I need to know the order of the pole at $z=\frac{\pi}{2}$. I don't know how this is found, but Wolfram Alpha tells me it's a double pole.
Using this info I've tried the formula:

$$\text{Res}\left(f(z),\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=\lim_{z\to \frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{d}{dz}\left(z-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^2\frac{1}{\sin(z)-1}$$

When I try to differentiate this things go from bad to worse. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remark that $\sin$, hence also $f(z) = \frac1{\sin z - 1}$, is symmetric around $z = \pi/2$.

It follows that its Laurent series can not have odd terms, and the residue has to be $0$.

Comment: How do I come to realize that this must be the case; that the Laurent series for f can not have odd terms due to this symmetry? This realization seems hard to not appreciate when it comes to finding residues

Comment: @FilipJohansen you can for example remark that for an even function $f(z) = \frac{f(z) + f(-z)}2$. If f is written as a Laurent series, on the RHS it is clear that all monomials of odd degree cancel, the LHS then shows that they were not there in the first place

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $\sin(\pi/2-z)=\cos(z)$, hence substituting $z=\pi/2-w$ it is:
$$\lim_{z \to \pi/2} \frac{(\pi/2-z)^2}{\sin(z)-1}=\lim_{w \to 0} \frac{w^2}{\cos(w)-1}=-2$$
So the pole is of order $2$. Hence, it is:
$$\text{Res}(f(z),z=\pi/2)=\lim_{z \to \pi/2} \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}z} \frac{1}{\sin(z)-1}(\pi/2-z)^2=\lim_{z \to \pi/2}\left[-\frac{\cos z}{(\sin z-1)^2}(\pi/2-z)^2-\frac{2(\pi-z)}{\sin z-1}\right]=0$$

Comment: I'm unsure about taking the limit in the last line; does it not matter that the denominators go to zero?